# Acces to a Value of a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to use the user input, to get the value of an Object attribute.
I tried some ways, but can't reach the goal.

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, n, t, parts):
        self.name = name
        self.n = n         
        self.t = t                  
        self.parts = parts                      


SensorCase = Product("Case", 7, 10, ("Bodenplatte", "Mikrocontroller", "Deckel"))

x = input("Name of the Object! ")
print(getattr(inpt, 'x'))
```

It should be like: The user types the name (Case) of the Object
and python prints me the value of the needed attribute out (n = 7)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share example of what you have already tried? It will give us something to work from

Comment: Something like that: x = input("Name of the Object! ")
print(getattr(x, 'n'))

Comment: Are you asking for the "name of an object" or the "name of an attribute" on a known object?

Comment: its edited now.

Comment: Do you have a list of products someplace?

Comment: No, havent got a list

Comment: With only one product, is the answer then `print(SensorCase.n)`? Why ask the user for input at all?

Comment: Sorry i  missunderstood you. There is now only one Object. Will add more later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are going to maintain a list of products and will search the list for a match based on the name entered by the user, then this should get you started:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, n, t, parts):
        self.name = name
        self.n = n         
        self.t = t                  
        self.parts = parts                      

all_product = [
    Product("Case", 7, 10, ("Bodenplatte", "Mikrocontroller", "Deckel")),
    Product("Fan", 7, 10, ("Bodenplatte", "Mikrocontroller", "Deckel")),
    Product("Footing", 7, 10, ("Bodenplatte", "Mikrocontroller", "Deckel")),
    Product("Widget", 7, 10, ("Bodenplatte", "Mikrocontroller", "Deckel"))
]

product_name = input("Enter product name: ")

for product in all_product:
    if product.name == product_name:
        print("{} : {}".format(product.name, product.n))
        break
else:
    print("no matching products found.")
```

Ultimately I think you will want to maintain the collection of products in a structure that is better suited to searching such as maybe a `dict` but this will get you going for now.

Comment: Thank You! Thats what I searched for. And thanks for the advice.